# Maven - Load resources from JAR file?

Tags: java, maven, jar, fatjar

I have a feeling I'm missing something critical when it comes to bundling resources in JAR files using Maven. My directory structure is the standard Maven one.

When using the IDE I reference the resource files as `\main\resources\public\images\path`  and it works fine, but when Maven css js and images dont work and the site looks bad. If I look in the jar I find all the css, js and images. When I try to open the css link in a browser I get a 404 error. Here is my pom.xml https://shrib.com/#XGISjWGN7QRfa2EIZD4r. In eclipse it works fine.
I use `Spark.staticFiles.location("public");` to load resources.

Comment: Please, show us some code so that we can help you better. This is confusing and doesn't make a lot of sense, so please try to help us help you by giving us some more information. Paste your pom file in your question, between triple backticks (```). Show us some of the code you're working with, and your html.

Comment: Jar files are for java and are put on your classpath and referenced from there -- you should never reference `main/resources` in your code. Maven will package the contents of the resources directory into the root of the jar. HTML, CSS, and Javascript aren't usually packaged in a jar -- they are usually kept separate and deployed to a file system on an http server. Though it is possible to package them in a jar, it's not really a great way to go about web content development.

Comment: thank you for your resopnse . this image show the jar file opened on winrar https://ibb.co/8PvfYf1

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment for Spark, however when you create an artifact (jar, fat or not), it merely doesn't contain `main/resources` folder (open the jar with tool like winrar and check yourself).

Another difficulty is that if you use something that works with `File` abstraction - its probably wrong inside the artifact. `File` describes a place on a filesystem, and you're trying to read something from the artifact.

Usually you can use inside the code that reads the resource:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/public/impages/path/sample.js")
```

Comment: thanks for your response .in my code i use `Spark.staticFiles.location("public");` and it work perfectly . and in the jar file when i open it with winrar  the folder public exists with all css js and images but not work . if i open path of one of the resources i got 404 not found .